# Доработка цикла

Tags: android, файлы

Есть цикл, который записывает в массив все папки с mp3 файлами. Но он очень долгий и кривой. Помогите его улучшить

```
   for(File file:files){
        if(file.isDirectory())
            gas(file,c);
        else
        if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                int i = dir.toString().lastIndexOf("/");
                d= dir.toString().substring(i+1);

            if (Collections.frequency(myList,d)>0) {}
            else{
            myList.add(d);
            url.add(dir.toString());
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Уточните насколько долгий, на каких объемах, и чем кривой?

Comment: и отфарматируйте, не понятно где заканчивается второй if

Comment: У меня 400 песен, 1,5 минуты.  Ну он проверяет каждую песню в папке, хотя достаточно одной ,что бы папка была добавлена, может как то сделать, что бы если в папке найдена песня , папка добавлялась, и цикл перескакивал на следующую папку

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
  File[] files = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
  for (File file : files) {
     File[] dir = file.listFiles();
     for (File f : dir) {
        if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".mp3")) {
           d = file.getPath();
           myList.add(d);
           url.add(dir.toString());
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Теперь 45с. Но в массиве каждая папка повторяется столько раз, сколько в ней песен. Я это решал так if (Collections.frequency(myList,d)>0). Т.е.если эта папка есть, её не добавляют ещё раз

Comment: ещё раз исправил ответ

Comment: Выбивает ошибку

Comment: так надо добавить в манифест права  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Добавил. При установки они не отображаются. А какая разница между WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: одно для записи, другое для чтения)

Comment: Но у меня WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE и пишет. Изменение и удаление данных на usb накопителе. А READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE игнорирует. И все равно ошибка

Comment: а что всё-таки за ошибка?

Comment: те ли это логи? судя по ним у пас проблема с восстановлением состояния активити

Comment: SELinux:  Could not open /data/system/packages.list:  Permission denied.
09-07 11:26:34.025 3215 3215 D     dalvikvm com.google.android.apps.plus

Comment: добавьте оба пермишна

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
09-07 10:56:34.238 27751 28922 E   AndroidRuntime                               Process: com.mycompany.myapp18, PID: 27751
09-07 10:56:34.238 27751 28922 E   AndroidRuntime                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-07 10:56:34.238 27751 28922 E   AndroidRuntime                               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-07 10:56:34.238 27751 28922 E   AndroidRuntime                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-07

Comment: а вы с ui в doInBackground-е не общаетесь?

Comment: Нет. Мой цикл(из вопроса) работает